Raspberry Pi Pico with KX134 accelerometer not being recognised despite being detected
I'm using the code below to communicate between a Raspberry Pi Pico and a KX134 accelerometer connected over I2C. The device is being detected by a ping, however the program itself does not register it as being connected. I'm using the qwiic_kx13x library, which in itself depends on the qwiic_i2c library (links pasted below). Thank you in advance :)
https://github.com/sparkfun/Qwiic_I2C_Py
https://github.com/sparkfun/Qwiic_KX13X_Py
import qwiic_i2c
import qwiic_kx13x
import time
import sys

# Initialize I2C driver (assuming qwiic_i2c doesn't support custom SDA/SCL)
my_bus = qwiic_i2c.get_i2c_driver(sda=4, scl=5, freq=100000)

ping_result = my_bus.ping(0x1F)  # Check for device presence at the correct address 0x1F
print("Device is connected:", ping_result)

def runExample():
    print("\nSparkFun KX13X Accelerometer Example 1\n")

    # Initialize the KX13X device at I2C address 0x1F
    myKx = qwiic_kx13x.QwiicKX13XCore(address=0x1F)  # Corrected address

    if not myKx.connected:
        print("The Qwiic KX13X Accelerometer device isn't connected to the system. Please check your connection", \
              file=sys.stderr)
        return

    if myKx.begin():
        print("Ready.")
    else:
        print("Make sure you're using the correct KX13X device")

    # Set the accelerometer range if needed, uncomment if range is required
    # myKx.set_range(myKx.KX132_RANGE8G)

    # Initialize with basic settings
    myKx.initialize(myKx.BASIC_SETTINGS)

    while True:
        # Get accelerometer data
        myKx.get_accel_data()
        print("X: {0}g Y: {1}g Z: {2}g".format(
            myKx.kx134_accel.x,
            myKx.kx134_accel.y,
            myKx.kx134_accel.z))
        
        time.sleep(0.02)  # Delay for the Output Data Rate, default 50Hz (1/50 = 0.02)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        runExample()
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
        print("\nEnding Example 1")
        sys.exit(0)



I've tried pinging the device (shows as connected) and specifying an exact I2C address (0x1F) instead of allowing it to choose the default. None of these worked.

could you detail the output you are currently getting?  Is an exception being thrown?  Is it just hitting the if not myKx.connected branch?  Does it work if you comment out the global level my_bus and ping attempt (as perhaps that is blocking the new connection attempt within your example function)?

Yeah, it's hitting that branch. It doesn't work even after that's commented-out. Here's the error: "Device is connected: True
SparkFun KX13X Accelerometer Example 1
The Qwiic KX13X Accelerometer device isn't connected to the system. Please check your connection"

What happens if you define my_bus within your runExample() function and pass it to your initialization statement as the i2c_driver parameter?
i.e. myKx = qwiic_kx13x.QwiicKX13XCore(address=0x1F, i2c_driver=myBus).  You're passing specific args when creating the driver you ping against, but without passing a driver to the object initialization, it just gets the system default driver, which might not be the same one.   You could also try checking the value of myKx._i2c to check the info of the default driver it is getting and comparing it.
